# Remove nodes individually from Solr Search index

Tags: 7, search

I know you can choose which content types to exclude. However, is there a way of removing specific nodes from the Solr index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you've run across this module yet as it is a recent addition to drupal.org but it looks like it's right up your alley.

[Apache solr exclude](http://drupal.org/project/1118602)

Comment: Looks good, shame no current release. Ill contact the module dev and see if he needs a hand.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what I wrote the module for. There's a release now and I moved the module to [Apache Solr Node Exclude](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_exclude) because I botched the project creation the first time.